# Coding system issues broke my emacs

Tags: yasnippet, character-encoding

I was messing with trying to get emojis to display and I broke my emacs by messing with the coding system settings somehow. After my desktop file failed to load, I uninstalled unicode-fonts and deleted anything from my init file that messed with the coding system, such as:

```
;;(set-default-coding-systems 'utf-8-unix)
;;(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)
```

Now,when I launch emacs, I get weird errors like the following backtrace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable 爨煥極敲✠慹湳灩数⥴ਊ㬻眠楨整灳捡⁥敲潭楶杮映湵瑣潩獮映潲⁭慍湧牡匠敶湥㬠㬻㬻㬻㬻㬻㬻㬻㬻㬻㬻㬻㬻㬻਻搨晥湵礠獡猭琭楲⵭敬瑦⠠⥳ ∠敒潭敶眠楨整灳捡⁥瑡琠敨戠来湩楮杮漠⁦⹓ਢ†椨⁦猨牴湩ⵧ慭捴⁨尢恜⁛瑜湜牜⭝•⥳ ††⠠敲汰捡ⵥ慭捴⁨∢琠琠猠਩††⥳਩⠊敤畦⁮慹⵳⵳牴浩爭杩瑨⠠⥳ ∠敒潭敶眠楨整灳捡⁥瑡琠敨攠摮漠⁦⹓ਢ†椨⁦猨牴湩ⵧ慭捴⁨嬢尠屴屮嵲尫❜•⥳ ††⠠敲汰捡ⵥ慭捴⁨∢琠琠猠਩††⥳਩⠊敤畦⁮慹⵳⵳牴浩⠠⥳ ∠敒潭敶眠楨整灳捡⁥瑡琠敨戠来湩楮杮愠摮攠摮漠⁦⹓ਢ†礨獡猭琭楲⵭敬瑦⠠慹⵳⵳牴浩爭杩瑨猠⤩਩ਊ搨晥湵礠獡猭牴湩ⵧ敲敶獲⁥猨牴਩†刢癥牥敳愠猠牴湩⁧呓⁒慭畮污祬琠⁯敢挠浯慰楴汢⁥楷桴攠慭獣瘠牥楳湯⁳‼㔲∮ ⠠灡汰⁹✣瑳楲杮 ††††爨癥牥敳 ††††⠠瑳楲杮琭ⵯ楬瑳猠牴⤩⤩ਊ搨晥湵礠獡琭楲浭摥挭浯敭瑮猭慴瑲⠠਩†吢楨⁳畦据楴湯爠瑥牵獮怠潣浭湥⵴瑳牡❴琠楲浭摥戠⁹桷瑩獥慰散⹳ਢ†礨獡猭琭楲⁭潣浭湥⵴瑳牡⥴਩⠊敤畦⁮慹⵳牴浩敭ⵤ潣浭湥⵴湥⁤⤨ ∠桔獩映湵瑣潩⁮敲畴湲⁳捠浯敭瑮攭摮‧牴浩敭⁤祢眠楨整灳捡獥椠⁦捠浯敭瑮攭摮‧獩渠瑯攠灭祴ਮ瑏敨睲獩⁥桴⁥敲敶獲摥漠瑵異⁴景映湵瑣潩⁮祠獡琭楲浭摥挭浯敭瑮猭慴瑲‧獩爠瑥牵敮⹤ਢ†椨⁦攨ⁱ氨湥瑧⁨潣浭湥⵴湥⥤〠਩†††礨獡猭牴湩ⵧ敲敶獲⁥礨獡琭楲浭摥挭浯敭瑮猭慴瑲⤩ †⠠慹⵳⵳牴浩挠浯敭瑮攭摮⤩਩)
  (eval-buffer #<buffer  *load*-675843> nil "/usr/share/yasnippet-snippets/prog-mode/.yas-setup..." nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 582
  (load-with-code-conversion "/usr/share/yasnippet-snippets/prog-mode/.yas-setup.el" "/usr/share/yasnippet-snippets/prog-mode/.yas-setup.el" t t)
  (load "/usr/share/yasnippet-snippets/prog-mode/.yas-setup" noerror t)
  (yas--load-yas-setup-file "/usr/share/yasnippet-snippets/prog-mode/.yas-setup")
  (yas--load-directory-2 "/usr/share/yasnippet-snippets/prog-mode" prog-mode)
  (yas--load-directory-1 "/usr/share/yasnippet-snippets/prog-mode" prog-mode)
  (apply yas--load-directory-1 ("/usr/share/yasnippet-snippets/prog-mode" prog-mode))
  (#f(compiled-function (&rest args2) #<bytecode 0x1580721bcaa9>))
  (yas--load-pending-jits)
  (yas-minor-mode 1)
  (yas-minor-mode-on)
  (yas-global-mode-enable-in-buffers)
  (run-hooks after-change-major-mode-hook)
  (run-mode-hooks emacs-lisp-mode-hook)
  (emacs-lisp-mode)
  (set-auto-mode-0 emacs-lisp-mode nil)
  (set-auto-mode)
  (normal-mode t)
  (after-find-file nil nil)
  (find-file-noselect-1 #<buffer init.el> "~/.emacs.d/init.el" :nowarn nil "~/.emacs.d/init.el" (5889992 2050))
  (find-file-noselect "/home/nate/.emacs.d/init.el" :nowarn)
  (desktop-restore-file-buffer "/home/nate/.emacs.d/init.el" "init.el" nil)
  (desktop-create-buffer 208 "/home/nate/.emacs.d/init.el" "init.el" emacs-lisp-mode (eldoc-mode override-global-mode global-auto-revert-mode projectile-mode ws-butler-mode flycheck-mode yas-minor-mode company-mode company-box-mode which-key-mode popper-mode popper-echo-mode) 25315 (25126 nil) nil nil ((buffer-display-time 25613 56468 927524 293000) (buffer-file-coding-system . utf-16le-with-signature-unix)) ((mark-ring (25026 746 746 746 25026))))
  (eval-buffer #<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/nate/.emacs.d/var/desktop/emacs-desktop" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 5639
  (load-with-code-conversion "/home/nate/.emacs.d/var/desktop/emacs-desktop" "/home/nate/.emacs.d/var/desktop/emacs-desktop" t t)
  (load "/home/nate/.emacs.d/var/desktop/emacs-desktop" t t t)
  (desktop-read)
  (#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x158071d8da0d>))
  (run-hooks after-init-hook delayed-warnings-hook)
  (command-line)
  (normal-top-level)
```

The file `/usr/share/yasnippet-snippets/prog-mode/.yas-setup.el` is not a bunch of chinese characters, it's just an ordinary looking lisp file. So I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: Is the problem reproducible? Do you see it if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If so, post a reproducible recipe. If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by emacs inferring the incorrect coding system for files. Solved by putting the following at the top of my init file to force utf-8:

```
;; There will be problems if it tries to load some file as the incorrect
;; coding system, so set that stuff up immediately
(prefer-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-default-coding-systems 'utf-8)
(set-terminal-coding-system 'utf-8)
(set-keyboard-coding-system 'utf-8)
;; backwards compatibility as default-buffer-file-coding-system
;; is deprecated in 23.2.
(if (boundp 'buffer-file-coding-system)
    (setq-default buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8)
  (setq default-buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8))

;; Treat clipboard input as UTF-8 string first; compound text next, etc.
(setq x-select-request-type '(UTF8_STRING COMPOUND_TEXT TEXT STRING))
```